# Visual studio 2008 catch exception that shouldnt be caught

Tags: c#, winforms, exception, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-debugging

On my winforms application I have an event **without try/catch** on textbox :

```
private void textBoxPassport_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {

       dicExsitsManagers[key] = value;

   }
```

I have a bug that this event is fired when the key is an empty string and I try to get value from the dictionary without proper key.

**This bug is not the issue here**. And I know I can check if the key exists.

This event being fired after other function with try/catch do some stuff on the form.

On VS2008 this exception is being caught by the try/catch of the other function while when launching the application outside the VS2008 this exception is not caught at all, and I get the windows ugly message of unhandled exception.

Why the VS2008 is catching this unhandled exception in the wrong try/catch?

**Update**

The problem is that the exception is being caught in the wrong place. My VS don't catch exception when I dont have try/catch. I use to see the VS2008 unhandled exception message, but not in this case.

Comment: When run in debug mode, any exception is catched by VisualStudio itself, to help you find issues and solve them.

Comment: `Why the VS2008 is catching` - because it helps you debug. People get upset [when it doesn't](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/debugger/archive/2010/05/12/visual-studio-debugger-fails-to-catch-unhandled-exception-for-a-windows-form-or-wpf-application.aspx).

Comment: "Debug -> Exceptions" and "Tools -> Options -> Debug" are couple places where you can customize this behavior... I.e. I prefer VS to stop on *all* exceptions when thrown irrespective if it will be caught or not by the code later.